# Play sound when press down and stop it when press up?

Tags: android, soundpool, piano

I have a sound with 7 seconds duration. I want to play it when pressing down and stop it after (for example 1 second) when pressing up. My code is like below, but I have a problem??? when pressing rapidly and several times, the sound play all 7 seconds and don't stop it. I want to create a simple piano.
what's the problem? Do you have any idea for this?

```
c.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            switch (event.getAction()) {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // Button Pressed
                                    SID1_c = soundPool.play(sound_c, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
                                    c.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key4);
                                                                           return true;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:// Button released

                                    handler =new Handler();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            soundPool.stop(SID1_c);
                                        }
                                    },90);

                                    return false;

                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During pressing down the `button` first you need to stop the `soundPool` if any present.

Write `soundPool.stop(SID1_c);` in `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:` before starting the `soundPool` again.

Comment: The previous problem is solved but a new problem occurs. by pressing rapidly and several times, the sound doesn't play very good?